# If Service Exists Condition

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How would you check if a WIN32 service exists and, if so, do some operation?

Comment: What service on what system? Please provide more contexts.

Comment: It will be a local service lets say named ABC.  I need to restart the service if it exists as part of a post build event in visual studio.  VS post build events are basically batch/dos (??) commands.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you can check if a specific service is running, as mentioned by bmargulies, using the "net" command, piping the result into "find".
Something like the following would check if a service was running, and if so stop it. You can then start it without worrying about if it was already running or not:

```
net start | find "SomeService"
if ERRORLEVEL 1 net stop "SomeService"
net start "SomeService"
```

If you're using findstr to do a search, as some of the other answers have suggested, then you would check for ERRORLEVEL equal to 0 (zero)... if it is then you have found the string you're looking for:

```
net start | findstr "SomeService"
if ERRORLEVEL 0 net stop "SomeService"
net start "SomeService"
```

Essentially most DOS commands will set ERRORLEVEL, allowing you to check if something like a find has succeeded.

Answer (score 20):

You can't do this in DOS, as DOS is not Windows and doesn't even have the concept of a "service".

In a Windows batch file you can use the `sc` command to find services:

```
sc query | findstr SERVICE_NAME
```

This will enumerate all services and yield their respective names.

You can search for a specific service with

```
sc query | findstr /C:"SERVICE_NAME: myservice"
```

Remember that this search is case-sensitive. You can add the `/I` switch to `findstr` to avoid that.

Answer (score 9):

Just an addendum to the accepted answer.  If you are looking to do other things than just restarting the service, and are looking to see if the service is installed.

```
sc query state= all | findstr /C:"SERVICE_NAME: MyService" 
if ERRORLEVEL 0 (**My Operation**)
```

In this case, the *state= all* is important since if the service is not started, it will be interpreted as not installed, which are two separate things.

Comment: As mentioned, this should be: `if not ERRORLEVEL 1 (**My Operation**)`

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the code below:

```
SC QUERY | FIND "SERVICE_NAME: MyService"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 NET STOP MyService
```

If **MyService** is not found, %ERRORLEVEL% will be set at 1 by FIND, else it will stay at 0. The instruction IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 allows you to test this last case and proceed with an operation on your service.

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 NET STOP MyService
```

will not work, because it executes the command if %ERRORLEVEL% is greater or equal to zero.

In a Visual Studio post build event, you have to put an:

```
EXIT 0
```

at the end because VS will detect that %ERRORLEVEL% != 0 and it will consider that the post build event has failed. Use this with care because this will hide all the errors in your command sequence.

With this trick, you can ignore the error and use this in your post build event to restart your service:

```
NET STOP MyService
NET START MyService
EXIT 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Should not be success tested: "if (not) errorlevel 1" ??

In windows shell "if errorlevel #" means the errorlevel is # or higher, so "if errorlevel 0" is alway true.

Comment: that is an answer to "how do I test whether running an executable worked" but it has nothing to do with seeing if a service is installed or running

Comment: I known, but I had no rights to write comment at this time.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`WMIC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531(VS.85).aspx):

First list all processes, then grep your process name. No result will be printed if it does not exist.

```
wmic service |findstr "ProcessName"
```

Example:

```
C:\>wmic service |findstr "Search"
FALSE        TRUE        Windows Search
```

Comment: @Burt: if statement in what language? batch, vbscript, c# or even perl? Certainly it will be much easier if you install wc (part of coreutils in gnu32), you will do c:>wmic service |findstr "Search"|wc -l, then write some code to grab that number to determine.

Answer (score 0):

Though there's an answer using wmic you can also the wql syntax that the command comes with:

```
wmic service where "name like '%%32TimeXXX%%'" get /Format:Value
```

Here's a whole script that uses the query above

```
@echo off

setlocal 
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
set "SERVICE_TO_FIND=32Time"
:: you can assign also an argument
rem set set "SERVICE_TO_FIND=%~1"
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

set "Name="
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%# in (
    `wmic service where "name like '%%%SERVICE_TO_FIND%%%'" get Name /Format:Value`
) do (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%] in ("%%#") do set "%%]"
)

if not defined Name (
    echo service like %SERVICE_TO_FIND% not found
    rem exit /b 1
) else (
    echo service found [%Name%]
)

endlocal
```